# \dotfill and glossaries

Tags: glossaries, fill

I have a glossary and I like to finish each entry by "See page x". I have added a \dotfill before so that we see "DESCRIPTION.......See page x".
Unfortunately the line break doesn't work as intended. Actually I would like latex to book enough space to write "See page x" on one line, otherwise it should add a full new line filled with dots.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[xindy,toc,acronym,nopostdot]{glossaries} 
\setglossarystyle{altlist}
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{%
  \begin{description}[style=standard,labelindent=0pt,itemsep=5pt]%
}{\end{description}}
\renewcommand\glspostdescription{\def\hfill{\hskip 25pt plus 3fill}\dotfill \textit{see page}}

\renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}
\makeglossaries

\usepackage{enumitem}
\parindent 0in
\parskip 0.05in
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0.8\baselineskip plus 0.2\baselineskip minus 0.2\baselineskip}

\newglossaryentry{Alpha}
{ name=Alpha,
  description={Smoothing factor applied to the demand level in the various exponential smoothing models. In theory: \ensuremath{ 0 < \alpha \leq 1}, in practice: \ensuremath{0 < \alpha \leq 0.6}}}
\newglossaryentry{Gamma}
{ name=Gamma,
  description={Smoothing factor applied to the seasonality (either additive or multiplicative) in the triple exponential smoothing models. In theory: \ensuremath{ 0 < \gamma \leq 1}, in  practice: \ensuremath{0.05 < \gamma \leq 0.3}}}
\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to define a custom style in this case. The "see page" and location list can then be placed inside a box, which will prevent any line breaking within it:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[xindy,toc,acronym,nopostdot]{glossaries} 

\makeatletter
\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \setglossarystyle{altlist}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}{%
  \begin{description}[style=standard,labelindent=0pt,itemsep=5pt]%
  }%
  {\end{description}}
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
      \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]%
      \mbox{}\par\nobreak\@afterheading
      \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription
      {\def\hfill{\hskip 25pt plus 3fill}\dotfill\mbox{\textit{see page} ##2}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}
\makeatother
\setglossarystyle{mystyle}

\makeglossaries

\parindent 0in
\parskip 0.05in
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0.8\baselineskip plus 0.2\baselineskip minus 0.2\baselineskip}

\newglossaryentry{Alpha}
{ name=Alpha,
  description={Smoothing factor applied to the demand level in the various exponential smoothing models. In theory: \ensuremath{ 0 < \alpha \leq 1}, in practice: \ensuremath{0 < \alpha \leq 0.6}}}
\newglossaryentry{Gamma}
{ name=Gamma,
  description={Smoothing factor applied to the seasonality (either additive or multiplicative) in the triple exponential smoothing models. In theory: \ensuremath{ 0 < \gamma \leq 1}, in  practice: \ensuremath{0.05 < \gamma \leq 0.3}}}
\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

[image: image of glossary]

Comment: Is there any easier way by playing with the command \renewcommand\glspostdescription{\def\hfill{\hskip 25pt plus 3fill}\dotfill \textit{see page}}
I am not even sure of what it does exactly tbh

Comment: @Nicolas You could use a non-breakable space (`\textit{see~page}` rather than `\textit{see page}`) but that wouldn't prevent a line break from occurring after "page" and before the first page number nor would it prevent any line breaking within the location list (if you have more than one page number). The `\glspostdescription` command is simply a hook to insert material after the description. The default definition inserts a full-stop. The `nopostdot` package option simply redefines `\glspostdescription` to do nothing. The `glossaries-extra` package also redefines `\glspostdescription`.